# Python 3 doesn't need __init__.py in this situation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import

Suppose I have:

```
src/
    __init__.py
    a.py
b.py
```

Suppose `__init__.py` is an empty file, and `a.py` is just one line:

```
TESTVALUE = 5
```

Suppose `b.py` is:

```
from src import a

print(a.TESTVALUE)
```

Now in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x, running `b.py` gives the result (`5`).

However, if I delete the file `__init__.py`, `b.py` still works in Python 3.x, but in Python 2.7, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src import a
ImportError: No module named src
```

Why does Python 2.7 exhibit different behaviour in this situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python 3 supports [namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) that work without an `__init__.py` file.
Furthermore, these packages can be distribute over several directories. This means all directories on your `sys.path` that contain `*.py` files will be recognized as packages.

This breaks backwards compatibility in Python 3 in terms of imports. A typical problem is a directory in your current working directory that has a name like a  library such as `numpy` and that contains  Python files. While Python 2 ignores this directory, Python 3 will find it first and tries to import the library from there. This has bitten me several times.